# Adding data to a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains Physician_Profile_City, Physician_Profile_State and Physician_Profile_Zip_Code. I ultimately want to stratify an analysis based on state, but unfortunately not all of the Physician_Profile_States are filled in. I started looking around to try and figure out how to fill in the missing States. I came across the `pyzipcode` module which can take as an input a zip code and returns the state as follows:

```
In [39]: from pyzipcode import ZipCodeDatabase
zcdb = ZipCodeDatabase()
zcdb = ZipCodeDatabase()
zipcode = zcdb[54115]
zipcode.state

Out[39]: u'WI'
```

What I'm struggling with is how I would iterate through the dataframe and add the appropriate "Physician_Profile_State" when that variable is missing. Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

[image: Dataframe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to iterate if the form of the data is a dict then you should be able to perform the following:

```
df['Physician_Profile_State'] = df['Physician_Profile_Zip_Code'].map(zcdb)
```

Otherwise you can call `apply` like so:

```
df['Physician_Profile_State'] = df['Physician_Profile_Zip_Code'].apply(lambda x: zcdb[x].state)
```

In the case where the above won't work as it can't generate a Series to align with you df you can apply row-wise passing `axis=1` to the df:

```
df['Physician_Profile_State'] = df[['Physician_Profile_Zip_Code']].apply(lambda x: zcdb[x].state, axis=1)
```

By using double square brackets we return a df allowing you to pass the `axis` param

Comment: thanks for the response. Unfortunately, none of the options you provided worked. I think the reason why is that the only way to convert a zip code into a string is by using the following code `zipcode = zcdb[54115] zipcode.state`, but in the answers you provided, there is never any accessing of the ZipCodeDatabase. Do you know how that might be accomplished?

Comment: OK, I see my error could you try example 2 or 3, I can't install pyzipcode as I'm using python 3, one method would be to generate a dict of all the states and their respective zip code. You can obtain a list of the unique values by calling `list(df['Physician_Profile_Zip_Code'].unique())`